# How to mount synology SMB2 share on ubuntu

Tags: samba, nas, smb

I'm having a hard time mount a SMB2 share from my synology to ubuntu server 16.04.

```
mount.cifs //NAMEOFNAS.domainname.local/Backup /mnt/NAS/ -U USERNAME
```

results in following error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

So checking the network share with smbclient results in another error:

```
 smbclient //NAMEOFNAS.domainname.local/Backup -U username
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter username's password:
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE
```

When doing the same but with a share on Windows server, I have no problem whatsoever. Is there something I have to configure in Synology NAS (i noticed it's configured to only use SMB2)?

Here is the output of `testparm` (only thing I changed was `domain` and `security=user`)

```
   # Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = AVR
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        server role = standalone server
        security = USER
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        server max protocol = SMB2
        max protocol = SMB2
        protocol = SMB2
        server min protocol = SMB2
        min protocol = SMB2
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
```

What can I do to mount this share please?

kr,
wouter

Comment: Some track : can you try mouting with IP address of the Synology. Also try without the FQDN (e.g. //NAMEOFNAS/Backup). I also guess that correct option for username is `-o username=username`

Comment: @olivierb2 I did make a mistake in my post, I corrected the syntax of `smbclient´. When I try it with `-o username=username´ it results in the same `NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE´ error. Uising the NETBIOS or the IP address does not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a PI to mount a DS Share into my nextcloud instance. For that reason I use the following mounting command:

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=ds-user,password=pw-of-ds-user,uid=33,gid=33,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,vers=2.1  //IP-of-NAS/share /mountpoint/where/to/mount
```

I will explain the command

- username and password should be clear I hope
- uid gid are the values for www-date to get it working under nextcloud
- `file_mode` set the permission for the mounting point
- `dir_mode` do the same for folders
- `vers=2.1` that was the most important to get it working, the version 2.0 was not working for my DS in combination with my Linux
- and of course the the source and destination

So you cannot copy and paste my command you must edit it to your needs, but I think the structure should be clear now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing your input. I needed to change version to `vers=2.0´ in order to get it working. I'll take a look which settings for uid gid will fit me but for now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit to quick. mount.cifs is working now but I need to add it to `/etc/fstab´ to mount it at boot. 
I added the following line `//IPADDRESSNAS/Backup/ /mnt/backup/ cifs credentials=/home/ncadmin/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,vers=2.0´  but receive following error in DMESG:
`CIFS VFS: Unknown vers= option specified: "2.0"´

Comment: I use it for several mounts in fstab with the following syntax:   `//server/share /mount/to cifs vers=2.1,credentials=/home/user/.smbcreds,uid=1001,gid=1001,iocharset=utf8,rw`  I dont know why exactly but I thought vers flag must be the first one. could you please try it.

Comment: and now I was to quick I simple transfer my bash script into fstab from my PI and then I mount it via mount -a `//192.168.178.200/photo /mnt/remote/nas/photo cifs username=username,password=password,uid=33,gid=33,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,vers=2.1`  what kind of Synology did you use? I'm wondering that my synology works with 2.1 and yours with 2.0 ...

Comment: I have an idea, normally you would run your cron under root, and maybe your smbcred file is under user xy, so 2 options, first try to insert user and password directly into fstab, if those works create a new smbcred file under root with the account.

Comment: You have good ideas :-). Indeed, with user+pw directly in fstab it worked. Now I have done `chown root:root .smbcredentials` and mounting works as a charm! Here is the line:

`//NAMEOFNAS.domain.local/Backup/ /mnt/Backup/ cifs vers=2.0,credentials=/home/admin/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0600`
Thanks!

Comment: Note: it is possible to [configure Synology DSM](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_winmacnfs_win) to have **Maximum SMB protocol** = **SMB3**, which means the `vers=2.1` will not be needed anymore.

Answer (score -1):

- edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`，change smb client version

  ```
  [global]

  # SMB protocol
  client min protocol = SMB2
  client max protocol = SMB3
  ```
- restart or reboot

  ```sh
  # restart smb service
  sudo systemctl restart smbd.service

  # or reboot
  sudo reboot
  ```
- try to link your NAS server

  ```sh
  smb://<nas-ip>
  ```